# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide when trying to call C function

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to call a C function from a python script. Here is my C file (privilegesFunctions.c) which is pretty basic:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "privilegesFunctions.h"

void helloWorld()
{
    printf("hello world");
}
```

My privilegesFunctions.h :

```
void helloWorld();
```

My python script :

```
 libCalc = ctypes.CDLL("./privLib.so")
 libCalc.helloWorld()
```

As you can see I have generated a library called privLib.so from my privilegesFunctions.c. I'm trying to call the helloWorld function but it doesn't work at all.

I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\deslo\OneDrive\Documents\Cours\Mines Ales\Prague\Secure Code\projet\main.py", line 121, in <module>
    mainApp()
  File "C:\Users\deslo\OneDrive\Documents\Cours\Mines Ales\Prague\Secure Code\projet\main.py", line 24, in mainApp
    libCalc = ctypes.CDLL("./privLib.so")
  File "C:\Users\deslo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide
```

Comment: `.so` is usually library files for Linux, not Windows. How did you generate the library?

Comment: @MikeCAT that's kinda not strictly true, it's a shared object as understood by the ELF dynamic linker, which you'd typically find on Linux system (and quite a few other unixoids), but nothing's wrong with using that linker on Windows - it's just that the python Luca is using has the default windows .dll loader and hence has no idea how to deal with ELF shared objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your .so file is probably a shared object as understood by the ELF dynamic linker, which you'd typically find on Linux system (and quite a few other unixoids), but nothing's wrong with using that linker on Windows (it **could** contain totally valid windows program binaries, it *probably* doesn't) – it's just that the python you're using has the default windows .dll loader and hence has no idea how to deal with ELF shared objects.

You need to use a toolchain that has the same binary format as the Python you're using. Since this is on windows, according to the paths your Python mentions, you'll need a windows-targetting toolchain.

Aside from the fact that .dll (i.e., the PE32 format) and .so (i.e. the ELF format) are fundamentally different in structure and a loader from one simply can't read the other, the problem is also that windows has a specific *calling convention* (namely, how does the stack need to be set up before calling a function? How do I pass different types and numbers of arguments to a function?)  that is simply different to that of systems that typically use .so libraries. That makes it impossible to just call a function for the different system without having quite some framework around it to emulate all these things.

So, you can't. Figure out how to produce .dll files with the compiler you're using. It can be relatively simple.